# Api fetch: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, html5, fetch

Estoy usando el API fetch, obtengo el error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` al hacer una petición de tipo GET, esta es la configuración que uso:

```
{
     "cache"      : "no-cache",
     "credentials": "same-origin",
     "headers": {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         "Accept"      : "application/json"
     },
     "method"  : "GET",
     "mode"    : "same-origin",
     "redirect": "follow",
     "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer"
}
```

El error se produce al tratar de leer el JSON de la respuesta: `response.json()`, esto lo hago después de comprobar que código de estado es 200.
Si trazo los headers de la respuesta, en cuanto al "Content-Type" obtengo `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

```
console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // text/html; charset=UTF-8`
```

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?
¿Por qué no obtengo un `Content-Type` de tipo JSON?

Comment: Seguramente la llamada no está funcionando bien y te devuelve algún tipo de respuesta de error en html, empezando por `<`

Comment: ¿Lo has probado en postman? Si te está devolviendo un html probablemente estés haciendo la petición al endpoint incorrecto o con los parametros incorrectos. Desafortunadamente eso ya depende de cómo este implementada la api que estás consumiendo y serían necesarios mas detalles.

Comment: Si la respuesta es vacía al hacer el `response.json()` da error

Comment: @Suso, la respuesta no es vacia, empieza por `<` tal como dice el error: **Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**, por eso he comentado que tiene pinta de HTML, quizas una página 404 o vete a saber

Comment: Yo me refiero a cuando una api te devuelve una respuesta tipo 200 o 400 o lo que sea pero sin datos. Al intentar hacer el response.json() si no tiene datos da fallo. Que igual no es su caso, pero a mi me ha pasado, y el mensaje de error era el mismo

Comment: Este es el típico error que ocurre cuando desde el servidor sale otra cosa, aparte del JSON que esperas. Eso puede ser un mensaje cualquiera, de error u otro, que pusiste bloques html, que tienes BOM ... etc. Debes revisar qué ocurre en el servidor, controlar bien el flujo de tu código allí y asegurarte que por pantalla no sale otra cosa que el json. Conviene que pongas un `header` adecuado si no lo tienes. Si no tienes acceso al servidor, para depurar, puedes cambiar temporalmente la respuesta esperada a `html` y mostrarla con `console.log`.

Comment: Prueba a hacer un `response.text()`

Comment: tal y como se indica aqui `console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // text/html; charset=UTF-8` ` el content-type es `text/html` y por tanto no se puede ejecutar `response.json()`